# How to populate android's sqlite data base at the install of the application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to populate my android's application's database at the install from a file, and then remove it to reduce the size of the application. Is this possible ?
Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to bundle a database file in the application assets, install the file in the databases/ directory and then remove the file from the assets. It is not possible to remove files from the assets, so the short answer is no.

If the file is huge, you might want to download it from a file share when the application starts. It's just a suggestion that may or may not work for your purposes.

EDIT:

Judging from your clarification (that the app don't have internet access), you can use a number of different techniques to keep the file size down. Having a list of INSERT statements is very efficient to parse and insert into the database, but it lacks flexibility if the database is changed, and incurs a lot of overhead in terms of size. If you have a simple data structure, you could have one value per line, or a CSV formatted data file.
Finally, don't forget that you can compress the data with e.g. ZIP, which you can read with ZipInputStream when starting the application. As always, it's necessary to weigh speed vs. memory.

Answer (score 1):

1- If you want that your database must have some default data when its installed, then you should provide a version of the database to the users, which have this default data.

2- Answer to your question:
You should include the SQL INSERT statements in a file. Read this file using code & run the statements which will insert the data. You can read from this file for example when the database is created & after the records are inserted delete that file.

Can you please provide more detail what actually you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a list that wil show some texts (long text) after a choice. And the application don't have access to internet. So I need a database to get many informations with the text to display. This is it.
So I want that the size of the application be small, and the performance not so bad ....

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below steps which is an alternate way to fill the app database.

**Step 1:** 
Create a GitHub Gist account.

**Step 2:** 
Create a text file with the data to be filled and get the raw URL

For Instance:

> string url =
>   "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME/0df1fa45aa11753de0a85893448b22de/raw/YourData.txt";

**Step 3:**
Retrieve the file contents from your app by invoking the WebService in GET request mode.

**Step 4:** 
Now fill the database with the received contents.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17461043)

Comment: I have mentioned an alternate way to fill the app database Sankar.

Comment: Please provide your answer with clear descriptions, While reviewing the answer, I am not sure whether these steps are an answer or  a question, anyway I have edited it, thanks for your response.

Comment: Thank you Sankar :)